# Given a total # of items and items per row, what column does an item belong to?

Tags: javascript, math

I have an application using CSS grid which will contain an variable number of grid elements, although I'll know the # of items in each row - is there an easy way to determine the column # of a given item?

ie. given 32 elements arranged into rows of 8, element number 9 is in column 1, element number 10 is in column two.

Currently I'm doing this:

```js
function getColumn(itemIndex, colsPerRow) {
  // its in the last column
  if (itemIndex % colsPerRow === 0) {
    return colsPerRow;
  }

  return itemIndex - (Math.floor(itemIndex/colsPerRow) * colsPerRow);
}
```

And it returns the correct answer, but I feel like there's a more simple way to solve this.

Comment: If you only need the column #, you can use the remainder operator. 


column_number = (item_number % number_of_items_in_each_row).

Comment: It's conventional to think and talk and compute in zero-based terms (counting starts at zero, the first index in an array is 0, etc), and if some part of the system expects one-based counting, (often, the user), do that adjustment at the edge of that system (like just before displaying the number to user).  So in this example, 32 elements arrayed in rows of 8 are 0-7, 1-15, 16-23, 23-31.  And @Toughyear has the column calculation right (in contrast to the current answers).

Comment: FYI, just noticed a typo in my comment above. It goes: 0-7, **8**-15, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take 1-based numbering into account:

```
column = (itemIndex - 1) % colsPerRow + 1
```

(no need in `if` clause)

Comment: @IMSoP I wasn't sure how % works in Javascript with negative numbers, but there no negative  numbers here :), thanks for pointing that

Comment: Heh :) I'm personally not convinced the nesting is clearer than a simple if statement, though.

Comment: @danh The example in the question puts item 9 in column 1 of 8, which implies the item above that is number 1, not 0

Comment: Agree, @IMSoP. Perhaps correcting that is the assistance the OP requires.

Comment: If you want to be really cute, I believe `(itemIndex % colsPerRow) || colsPerRow` will give the right result as well.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got the answer already: item number modulo column count.

```js
function getColumn(itemIndex, colsPerRow) {
  // its in the last column
  if (itemIndex % colsPerRow === 0) {
    return colsPerRow;
  }

  return itemIndex % colsPerRow;
}

console.log(
  getColumn(1,9),
  getColumn(2,9),
  getColumn(3,9),
  getColumn(4,9),
  getColumn(5,9),
  getColumn(6,9),
  getColumn(7,9),
  getColumn(8,9),
  getColumn(9,9),
  getColumn(10,9),
  getColumn(11,9)
);
```